# Why is $scope not working in Angular 1.6.1?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, this

### Background

After following the [AngularJS tutorial on codeSchool](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js) and reading some StackOverflow questions, I decided to start using `$scope` in order to avoid the hassle of having to define a `var self = this;` variable.

### Problem

The problem is that `$scope` seems to not be binding anything and nothing works when I use it. I have no idea why, but if I use a `var self = this;` variable my code will work, even though in theory (according to what I know) `$scope` should do the same ...

### Code

Let's say I have a page where I want to display a big list of numbers. Let's also say I have pagination, and that I want the default amount of Numbers per page to be 4. Let's also assume that after each request to the server, I set the amount of Numbers shown per page to 4 again.

**app.js**

```
/*global angular, $http*/

(function() {
    var app = angular.module("myNumbers", []);

    app.directive("numberFilter", function() {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl: "number-filter.html",
            controller: function($scope, $http) {
                $scope.filter = {
                    itemsPerPage: 4
                };

                $scope.makeRequest = function(numberList) {
                    console.log("Received submit order");

                    $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: 'https://myNumberServer.com/api/v1/getPrimes',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                        }
                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                        numberList= response.data.entries;
                        $scope.totalPages = response.data.totalPages;
                        $scope.filter = {itemsPerPage: 4};
                        console.log("success!");
                    }, function errorCallback(response) {
                        console.log('Error: ' + response);
                    });
                };
            },
            controllerAs: "filterCtrl"
        };
    });
})();
```

**number-filter.html**

```
<form ng-submit="filterCtrl.makeRequest(myNumbers.numberList)"> 
        <div >
            <label for="items_per_page-input">Items per page</label>
            <input  type="number" id="items_per_page-input" ng-model="filterCtrl.filter.itemsPerPage">
        </div>            

        <div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

There are two expected behaviors that should happen and don't:

1. When I click submit, I should see in the console `"Received submit order"` and I don't.
2. The `input` element should be initialized with 4 when I load the page.

Both of these behaviors will happen if I use the  `var self = this;` trick and replace all mentions of `$scope` with `self`.

Questions:

1. Why is this not working? Am I missing some closure?

Comment: I think `controllerAs` alias syntax works only if you bind methods or properties in controller instance `this` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `controllerAs` syntax so when you use that your  model needs to be assigned to the controller object itself, not to $scope

Example

```
controller: function($scope, $http) {

  var vm = this; // always store reference of "this"

  // use that reference instead of $scope
  vm.filter = {
    itemsPerPage: 4
  };

  vm.makeRequest = function(numberList) {
    console.log("Received submit order");

    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://myNumberServer.com/api/v1/getPrimes',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      numberList = response.data.entries;
      vm.totalPages = response.data.totalPages;
      vm.filter = {
        itemsPerPage: 4
      };
      console.log("success!");
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      console.log('Error: ' + response);
    });
  };
},
```